# When $ sign is in the Id of the ASP TextBox, FindControl method returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, clientid

I am writing to you because I want to understand what is happening.

In my code, I add controls dynamically to the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` (I extended it). After some action on the page, I am checking if the ID of the Control from `Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` is the one, which I saved earlier in ViewState.

On .Net 3.5 everything works fine, but after switching my project to .Net 4 this doesn't work, because `Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` returns Inherit ClientId, and I keeped in ViewState only short Id of my control. I fixed it by using `Page.FindControl` method. It works for LinkButtons, Buttons and DropDowns, but not for TextBoxes, because `Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` returns name of my TextBox...

So I change ClientIdMode for my TextBox to Static, like `'string$string'`. But still `Page.FindControl` was returned null. I have read that if TextBox is generated dynamically and it is nested in some controls, this method is not able to find it.

My **first** question. Why method `Page.FindControl` is not able to find nested TextBox, but it can handle with others control like DropDown or LinkButton?

But I handle this problem also. I wrote recursive kind of `Page.FindControl` and I can find my TextBox. But in this moment I came across a problem again. Value of this TextBox is old (I write 6, but in the Text property there is still 1). My first idea was that this is because I was doing it too early - in `OnPagePreLoad` method.

But then I change Id of my TextBox from `string$string` to 'string_string' and it started to work fine (value of my text box is that I wrote).

And this is my **second** question. Why dollar ($) sign cause I saw the old value?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` character is not valid in the ID property.  See [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information

Specifically,

> Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property.  **Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.**

Also, see [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.idseparator(v=vs.100).aspx) about the `IdSeparator` property.

Specifically:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

So replacing the `$` with an underscore seems like the right answer.